# Binding in MVVM without firing

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

Firstly, sorry for the unclear title! I could not find a way to better describing my problem.

I'm learning MVVM now and I have a question, as it is difficult for me to understand it.

I have a class `Bindable`

```
class Bindable<T> {
typealias Listener = ((T) -> Void)
var listener: Listener?

var value: T {
    didSet {
        listener?(value)
    }
}

init(_ v: T) {
    self.value = v
}

func bind(_ listener: Listener?) {
    self.listener = listener
}

func bindAndFire(_ listener: Listener?) {
    self.listener = listener
    listener?(value)
}
}
```

and as you can see I have here `bind` and `bindAndFire` methods. I completely understand why we use `bindAndFire`, as it changes `value` parameter so we can use it, but the only thing what I cannot understand is why do we need to use sometimes ONLY `bind` method?

For example here:

```
viewModel?.showLoadingHud.bind {
        PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView = PKHUDSystemActivityIndicatorView()
        $0 ? PKHUD.sharedHUD.show() : PKHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
    }
```

It will only set the `listener` parameter and nothing else. 
Could you please explain why we need ONLY bind without changing value of it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Seems to me the bind sets up the listener to be notified for changes, but not actually process the current value. bind and fire will wire up to listen for changes AND process the current value in the listener event handler.